# Power analysis on paired proportions data

Tags: statistical-power, proportion, paired-data

I'm interested in running a two-sided power analysis on paired proportions data and hope to use the stats:power.prop.test or pwr::pwr.2p.test function, but not sure if the functions assume paired or unpaired samples. Does it matter? I didn't see anything in the documentation, but should I just assume it means unpaired samples? What are the implications of assuming it does paired samples when it doesn't?

My goal is to

**1.** know the amount of power I have for detecting a (for example) 30% change in species occurrence (a positive observation at # of sites out of N=47 total, each season) between 2 seasons, 4 seasons, etc.. Alpha=0.05.

**2.** How many sites per season (N) would I need to get a power of 80%.

Does this seem correct for paired data (same 47 sites each season)?

```
> pwr.2p.test(n = 47, h = ES.h(0.75,0.61), power = NULL, 
+                  sig.level = 0.05, alternative = "two.sided")

     Difference of proportion power calculation for binomial distribution (arcsine transformation) 

              h = 0.3017843
              n = 47
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.3099007
    alternative = two.sided

NOTE: same sample sizes

> pwr.2p.test(n = NULL, h = ES.h(0.75,0.61), power = 0.8, 
+                  sig.level = 0.05, alternative = "two.sided")

     Difference of proportion power calculation for binomial distribution (arcsine transformation) 

              h = 0.3017843
              n = 172.3627
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.8
    alternative = two.sided

NOTE: same sample sizes
```